# Ubuntu does not detect 3,5mm headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, audio-jack

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS E402SA-FR291T laptop.

When I plug my headphones into the 3,5mm jack nothing happens at all as far as I can tell. I cannot see the headphones in the audio settings, it only shows "Speakers - Built-in Audio" as an option.

I've tried running alsamixer and it gives me the following:

[image: Alsamixer]

Also, if I jack up the sound on the "*Headphone*" I do get sound from it, but that does not stop the speakers from emitting the same sound. Any ideas?

I'm fairly new to Linux so detailed instructions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The 'MM' under the columns means it's muted. Crazy simple fix, just press 'M', unmute the columns and it'll work fine.

Comment: `MM` with light foreground and dark background means *un*muted. The muted setting has it as light foreground on dark background. -1

Comment: Nope. If it's unmuted it doesn't show 'MM' at all. It only shows MM if muted, I just had the same issue and the settings I have were identical to the screenshot above. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: On my system and every other system I used, `alsamixer` behaves as described in my previous comment.